# 1秒間1回のリクエスト制限がある外部のWeb APIを利用するWebアプリケーションのAPIリクエスト超過対策

Tags: php, api, http

一般公開されている外部のWeb APIを利用したWebアプリケーションを開発します。
Webアプリケーションにて利用者に入力されたキーワードをそのWeb APIに渡すと、Web APIからキーワードに関連したデータが返却されます。

そのWeb APIは1秒間に1回のリクエスト制限があります。
したがって複数の利用者からの同時大量アクセスがあった場合、リクエスト制限が発生します。

そこで、Web APIへのリクエストを1秒間1回に収めるために、Webアプリケーションへのアクセスを順番待ちで捌くような制御をする必要があると考えています。
下記のような対策方法案があります。

1. DBに順番待ちテーブル(窓口の整理券のような役割)を設ける
2. クライアントからリクエストを受けたら順番待ちテーブルに新規レコードを追加
3. 順番待ちテーブルのレコード数から待ち時間を決定(例:自分より前に3人並んでいたら待ち時間は3秒間)
4. サーバー側では待ち時間分スリープ処理を実施した後にWeb APIへリクエストを実施し、クライアントへレスポンスを返す
5. 順番待ちテーブルから対象レコードを削除

この対策方法(設計)は適切でしょうか？
APIリクエスト超過に対して他に良い対策が思いつかず、この対策方法・設計で進めていいのか悩んでいます。
よろしくお願いします。

### ※システム構成

- ロードバランサにWebサーバ複数台(Nginx)をぶら下げます。
- データベースサーバ1台(MySQL)
- PHP

### ※その他

- Web APIへのリクエストを節約するためWebサーバではキャッシュを利用します。
- 定期バッチ処理などでWeb APIからデータを取得しておくことで、Web APIへのリクエスト数を抑える方法は現実的でないため考えていません。

Comment: 待ち受けキューに突っ込む役割と外部apiをcalする役割を分割して、非同期にすればいかがですか？今のまま(キューへの投入とリクエストを同一のアクターがこなす方式)だと、テーブルのコミット前に次のリクエストが来ると、要件を満たせないです。

Comment: @あとわいと  コメントありがとうございます。
私の理解が足りず解釈が難しいので確認させてください。
外部APIはWebアプリケーション経由でコールします。
役割を分割して非同期にする、ということは、クライアントからWebサーバに対して計2回リクエストする認識で合っていますか？

Comment: ３つ作ります。現状のapiこれは、一旦後続のapiへのキューに問い合わせをプッとだけして呼び出しもとに反りますこの時、呼び出しを一意に決定できるIDを作成します。これは、シーケンスを利用すれば簡単でしょう、二つ目はキューを1秒感覚でポーリングする常駐プロセス。1びょうごとにゲットして、後続のapiに問い合わせ,その結果をデータベースに格納します。三めは結果紹介のapi,引数に前述のIDを添えてデータを引き出します。後続の処理があればここで実装します。

Comment: @あとわいと 良くわかりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

うえでコメントした内容を図にしてみました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: とても見やすい図ですが1点だけ、「皇族」は「後続」の間違いですかね。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。お恥ずかしいtypoを。。。。修正させていただきました。